# How to insert image and text into FPDF PDF generated file

Tags: php, fpdf

```html
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('pdf');
require('fpdf.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $email = $_POST['email'];
 $comment = $_POST['comment'];
 $url = $_POST['url'];
$pdf=new FPDF();


$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->Image('logo.png',18,13,33);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',14);
$pdf->Cell(50,10, $name,1,1);
$pdf->Cell(50,10, $email,1,7);
$pdf->Cell(50,10, $url,1,1);
$pdf->Cell(50,10, $comment,1,1);


$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',7); 

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',6);
$pdf_name=$pdf->Output("","S"); 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO pdf VALUES('','".mysql_real_escape_string($pdf_name)."')");
 echo "insert successful!";
}
}
?>
```

This is the part where I save the pdf into mysql database as string I want to ask how can I save it as blob data at the pdf->output().

```html
<?php
mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
mysql_select_db('pdf');

$query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pdf WHERE id='11'");
$row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query);

$content = $row['pdf_file'];
header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header("Content-Length: ".strlen(content));
print $content;

?>
```

This is the part where I display the pdf file that save as blob but it return error it cannot display the file.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is while inserting data into your Db,

If your inserting blob data( or Binary data) into sql then better to not use to  escape string. Because it may possible to do sql injection through an pdf that a user could upload, but your genrating PDF your self, so there is a very(Might be 0) risk to do sql injunction.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pdf VALUES('','".mysql_real_escape_string($pdf_name)."')");
```

to

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pdf VALUES('','".$pdf_name."')");
```

If you want to You use base64_encode to keep your data will not have problems with characters of any kind, this is very common way to keep Blob data or transfer data in the network. And to get it back use base64_decode.

i.e, if you want to insert data in to db, use base64_encode () while after selected data from the db you have to use base64_decode()